# Convert timestamp to date in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, date-formatting

I want to convert a `timestamp` in MySQL to a date.

I would like to format the user.registration field into the text file as a `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Here is my SQL:

```
$sql = requestSQL("SELECT user.email, 
                   info.name, 
                   FROM_UNIXTIME(user.registration),
                   info.news
                   FROM user, info 
                   WHERE user.id = info.id ", "export members");
```

I also tried the date conversion with:

```
DATE_FORMAT(user.registration, '%d/%m/%Y')
DATE(user.registration)
```

I echo the result before to write the text file and I get :

> email1;name1;DATE_FORMAT(user.registration, '%d/%m/%Y');news1
>
> email2;name2;news2

How can I convert that field to date?

Comment: Its saving the file exactly like that?  What is the code you're using to run the sql query?

Comment: I edited my question, requeteSQL is running the query

Answer (score 516, accepted):

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`user.registration`), '%e %b %Y') AS 'date_formatted'
```

Comment: As of MySQL 5.6.23, I find that the value to FROM_UNIXTIME() should be entered directly: i.e., 

DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(user.registration), '%e %b %Y') AS 'date_formatted'

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`users`.`user_created_at`),'%Y-%b-%e') = '2015-03-06'
is this correct format or should i modify this?

Comment: @DheerajThedijje this shows up as 2018-Nov-6. You may be looking for `'%Y-%m-%d'` as you'd format it in PHP `(date('Y-m-d',$row->user_created_at))` - this (both variants, SQL and PHP) shows up as 2018-11-06

Comment: In case you want to add the time in this fashion "hh:mm:ss", add this to the format string ' %H:%i:%s'

Comment: So is this storing the datetime of that timestamp from the perspective of London, or New York, or where the trigger is run or where the client is run?

Answer (score 100):

To just get a date you can [`cast`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) it

```
cast(user.registration as date)
```

and to get a specific format use [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
date_format(registration, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc4bd/1)

Comment: It gives the same result, cast(user.registration as date) is displayed instead of the value of the field

Comment: This worked though - cast(from_unixtime(user.registration) AS date)

Comment: i have specific date format that its worked for me as well as possible thanks

Comment: use "as DATETIME" to get hour minutes and seconds too

Answer (score 86):

### Convert timestamp to date in MYSQL

**Make the table with an integer timestamp:**

```
mysql> create table foo(id INT, mytimestamp INT(11));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

**Insert some values**

```
mysql> insert into foo values(1, 1381262848);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

**Take a look**

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+------+-------------+
| id   | mytimestamp |
+------+-------------+
|    1 |  1381262848 |
+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Convert the number to a timestamp:**

```
mysql> select id, from_unixtime(mytimestamp) from foo;
+------+----------------------------+
| id   | from_unixtime(mytimestamp) |
+------+----------------------------+
|    1 | 2013-10-08 16:07:28        |
+------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Convert it into a readable format:**

```
mysql> select id, from_unixtime(mytimestamp, '%Y %D %M %H:%i:%s') from foo;
+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | from_unixtime(mytimestamp, '%Y %D %M %H:%i:%s') |
+------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | 2013 8th October 04:07:28                       |
+------+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: please fix %h to %H

Answer (score 24):

If the `registration` field is indeed of type `TIMESTAMP` you should be able to just do:

```
$sql = "SELECT user.email, 
           info.name, 
           DATE(user.registration), 
           info.news
      FROM user, 
           info 
     WHERE user.id = info.id ";
```

and the registration should be showing as yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: I tried but I get the same result: DATE(user.registration) is display instead of the value of the field

Comment: as someone suggested, are you able to run the query successfully using mysql client directly? I haven't heard of the requeteSQL function, what exactly does it do?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to use a mysql client directly, I don't have my own server... I have provided requeteSQL, basically it just run the query and test if error to send emails...

Comment: Actually I realized my field was a BIGINT type and not a TIMESTAMP. Only the content was a timestamp (1328649722), so that's why it didn't work. Now everything is good with FROM_UNIXTIME!

Answer (score 16):

`FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp, [format])` is all you need

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(user.registration, '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'date_formatted'
```

`FROM_UNIXTIME` gets a number value and transforms it to a `DATE` object,
or if given a format string, it returns it as a string.

The older solution was to get the initial date object and format it with a second function `DATE_FORMAT`... but this is no longer necessary

Answer (score 13):

Just use mysql's DATE function:

```
mysql> select DATE(mytimestamp) from foo;
```

Comment: `SELECT DATE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())` spits `NULL` in my MySQL 5.7.14

Comment: try DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())

Answer (score 8):

You should convert `timestamp` to `date`.

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(user.registration, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS 'date_formatted'
```

[FROM_UNIXTIME](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-from_unixtime-function.php)

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting the query in your output you need to show us the code that actually echos the result. Can you post the code that calls requeteSQL?

For example, if you have used single quotes in php, it will print the variable name, not the value

```
echo 'foo is $foo'; // foo is $foo
```

This sounds exactly like your problem and I am positive this is the cause.

Also, try removing the @ symbol to see if that helps by giving you more infromation.

so that

```
$SQL_result = @mysql_query($SQL_requete); // run the query
```

becomes

```
  $SQL_result = mysql_query($SQL_requete); // run the query
```

This will stop any error suppression if the query is throwing an error.

Answer (score 3):

I did it with the 'date' function as described in [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) :

```
(SELECT count(*) as the-counts,(date(timestamp)) as the-timestamps FROM `user_data` WHERE 1 group BY the-timestamps)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the datatype of the column, you can simply convert first from `TIMESTAMP` to `INT`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name INT;
```

And then `INT` to `DATE`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name DATE;
```

But, if you didn't mean to change a column, but wanted SELECT only, then you can use date() function:

```
SELECT date(your_timestamp_column) FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to convert a record 1580707260

Usually, I am using online timestamp converter

Want to showcase it in the query result

Please try this

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(field name from table), '%e %b %Y')
```

AS 'display name for result'

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT strftime("%Y-%d-%m", col_name, 'unixepoch') AS col_name
```

It will format timestamp in milliseconds to yyyy-mm-dd string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command `FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp, [format]);` but sometimes timestamp is in a long value that you have to remove 3 last values to 0.
for instance you use this command `from_unixtime(e.EVENT_TIME/1000);`
this way solve my problem.