# How to handle null Datetime using MySQL Reader

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm trying to iterate my MySQL DB using MySqlDataReader in C# .Net but I'm having trouble checking whether any DateTime columns are null or empty first. I've made a dynamic list ("MyList") and plan to iterate the DB and add each item with custom fields, some of which are DateTimes, but during this process I'm getting the error "This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

With string values I usually use this inline syntax to check if the columns are null:

```
Value = reader["Name"] != null ? reader["Name"].ToString() : ""
```

but there seems to be a different process for DateTime columns which I can't figure out, here's a snippet of my code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

List<dynamic> MyList = new List<dynamic>();

using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=database;user  id=user;password=password")){
    con.Open(); 

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Items";
    DateTime defaultDate = DateTime.Now;

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,con);

    using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
        while(reader.Read()){ 
            MyList.Add(new {
                Value = reader["Name"] != null ? reader["Name"].ToString() : "",
                Date = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("Date")) != null ? reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("Date")) : defaultDate
            });
        }   
    }   

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at Nullable types. (Hint: datetime?)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Helper function like the following (that SO User [Rein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100142/rein)'s has written up in a related Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870697/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string/870771#870771)) that will take care of this requirement for you for *any database type* that can be Null.

i.e.

```
Date = ConvertFromDBVal<DateTime>(reader.GetOrdinal("Date"));
```

using the generic function:

```
public static T ConvertFromDBVal<T>(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value) {
        return default(T); // returns the default value for the type
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks awesome but I'm getting the error "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". What could this be?

Comment: My bad. `T` is the actual .Net `Type` you want to execute the helper function on. Fixed it to `DateTime`. Try it now. You should be able to use the same function for any other 'Type`. Example: Value = ConvertFromDBVal<string>(reader["Name"]);

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.TryParse` to detect if value is a valid DateTime,like this:

```
while(reader.Read()){
        if(reader["Date"] != DBNull.Value)
                DateTime.TryParse(reader["Date"].ToString(), out defaultDate);
        MyList.Add(new {
            Value = reader["Name"] != null ? reader["Name"].ToString() : "",
            Date = defaultDate
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the date into string in the Sql Query to parse it myself (see [convert timestamp to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251561/convert-timestamp-to-date-in-mysql-query)).

The sql query then look like :

```
 select DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s') as dateColumn from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySqlReader just like me, you can use this code:

```cs
int datahoralocalOrdinal;
if ((datahoralocalOrdinal = objReader.GetOrdinal("DATAHORALOCAL")) > 0 && !objReader.IsDBNull(datahoralocalOrdinal)) {
    object datahoralocal = objReader.GetValue(datahoralocalOrdinal);
        if (datahoralocal is MySqlDateTime msdt && msdt.IsValidDateTime) {
            DateTime.TryParse($"{msdt}", out DateTime dt);
            if (dt != null) {
                    view.date = new DateTimeOffset(dt).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
            }
        }
}
```