# How to select date from datetime Unix_timestamp column in mysql database using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Mysql Column send_date datetime format given below

```
1423305800
1423305866
1423305932
1423305998
1423306064
```

How to select only date from this table, my coding is:

```
 $date_from_calendar = strtotime('2015-02-06');

 $sql = "select * from use_info where user_id='$user_id' and date(send_date)= '$date_from_calendar' order by u_id DESC";
```

Why i am unable to get results from it?

Comment: Gordon please read my question carefully than answer , you are giving me wrong suggestion. If iam able to understand it from dev.mysql.com than i don't ask this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: . . You convert the unix time to a date, then you extract the date component.  You seem to understand date functions, so the only missing piece is the conversion from unix time to a date.

Comment: please make the correction where i am wrong?

Comment: gordon thats what iam asking $sql = "select * from use_info where user_id='$user_id' and unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(send_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) = '$date_from_calendar' order by u_id DESC";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, format it before comparing

```
$date_from_calendar = strtotime('2015-02-06');

$sql = "select * from use_info where user_id='$user_id' and unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(send_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) = '$date_from_calendar' order by u_id DESC";
```

Comment: You understand my question , absolutely correct, that's what i want ,Thanks Bro

Answer (score 0):

In php strtotime() function will convert a string date like ('2015-02-06') to timestamp which is what you used in your database, so you don't need to use date() function in your query, here is corrected code:

```
 $thatday = '2015-02-06';

 $sql = "select * from use_info where user_id='$user_id' and date(send_date)= '$thatday' order by u_id DESC";
```

Comment: This will only match records for the first second of the day, not the entire day.

Comment: send_date column contains date and time not only date

Comment: but send_date is in this format 1423305800
1423305866
1423305932
1423305998

Comment: i had try this but no result - $sql = "select * from use_info where user_id='$user_id' and date(send_date)= '2015-02-06' order by u_id DESC";

Comment: but when i try this iam getting correct result - $sql = "select * from use_info where user_id='$user_id' and send_date= '1423305800' order by u_id DESC";

Comment: 1423305800 is date and time both , iam getting 1 result only of this date and time , i want result for whole day

Answer (score 0):

If the `send_date` field is of type timestamp then you can convert it to a date.

```
$sql = "select * from use_info 
        where user_id='$user_id' 
        and date(send_date) = '2015-02-06'
        order by u_id DESC";
```

In the question you converted the timestamp to a date and compared it to a timestamp.

Alternatively you can "manually" search the entire day.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$start = strtotime('2015-02-06'); // start of the day 1423180800
$end = $start + (60 * 60 * 24);   // 24 hours after $start 1423267200

$sql = "select * from use_info 
        where user_id = $user_id 
        and send_date >= $start
        and send_date < $end 
        order by u_id DESC";
```

In the example above, we are matching all the records that occurred on or after `1423180800` and before `1423267200`.

Comment: Iam getting correct answer if i do this $sql = "select * from use_info where user_id='$user_id' and send_date= '1423305800' order by u_id DESC"; 1423305800 is date and time  , i only want to do for date

Comment: You want all the records that occurred in the 24 hour period of `2015-02-06` to `2015-02-07` correct? Or do you only want records that occurred for the second of `1423305800`?

Comment: The examples should work then. Are you taking into consideration time zones?

Comment: yes i think this will work , but why we cant extract only date from - 1423305800(this is date and time)

Comment: A time stamp such as `1423305800` only represents one second. It is recording the number of seconds that have elapsed since Jan 01 1970 (sometimes called the unix epoch). So when you want to get all the records that happen with in a 24 hour period you need to account for all the seconds that have elapsed in that period. You can convert from timestamp to date in mysql but there are a few hitches, for one the field to be converted needs to be a mysql datetime expression or a `TIMESTAMP` field. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251561/convert-timestamp-to-date-in-mysql-query.

Comment: code-jaff had done it - $sql = "select * from use_info where user_id='$user_id' and unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(send_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) = '$date_from_calendar' order by u_id DESC";