# How to select Max(id) with the difference between two timestamp superior to five minute in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to select the Max('id') with the difference of 5 minutes between two timestamp in mysql.

My timestamp field is `sent`

I did

```
SELECT Max('id') FROM `mytable` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `sent`, NOW()) > 5
```

But this did not work. It sent me and empty result

This is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `to_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `sent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `read_statu` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `to` (`to_id`),
  KEY `from` (`from_id`),
  KEY `direction` (`is_deleted`),
  KEY `read` (`read_statu`),
  KEY `sent` (`sent`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=201 ;

INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`, `from_id`, `to_id`, `message`, `sent`, `read_statu`, `is_deleted`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 'Juste un test pour moi meme', 1425729597, 1, 0),
(2, 2, 1, 'Hello', 1425729612, 1, 0),
(3, 2, 1, ' <3  (L)  :prayer:  :tkh:  :heart:  :-$ ', 1425729922, 1, 0),
(4, 2, 1, ' <3  (L)  :prayer:  :tkh:  :heart:  :-$ ', 1425729927, 1, 0),
(5, 1, 2, 'Ok', 1426010868, 0, 0);
```

**Please How to select Max(id) with the difference between two timestamp superior to five minute in Mysql ?**

Thanks

Comment: what is the second timestamp? Please add the expected result according to your data.

Comment: @Strawberry Is myIsam not good ? Which one should i have choosen /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` should be escaped with backticks not single quotes

```
SELECT Max(`id`) FROM `mytable` ...
```

By using single quotes there, MySQL was using the literal string `'id'` instead of the column `id`.

Also, you need to understand that `TIMESTAMPDIFF` does not accept UNIX timestamps as the arguments, but rather valid MySQL datetime expressions.  This function is used to return a timestamp-like interval value given two datetime expression values.

IMO, you would help yourself greatly by storing `sent` as a datetime field rather than Unix timestamp.  Unix timestamps are generally a poor design decision in MySQL tables if you ever need to do any calculations/filtering, etc. on the field.

Assuming you change `sent` to a datetime field, your query could look like this:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`)
FROM `myTable`
WHERE `sent` > DATESUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Assuming you want to keep your Unix timestamp field format the query might look like this:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`)
FROM `myTable`
WHERE `sent` > UNIXTIMESTAMP(DATESUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE))
```

You see you just have an extra conversion to make  to work with UNIX timestamp.

Note also the format of the `WHERE` clause here.  I did not use the field being filtered against as part of the calculation as you did in your query.  Your approach would disallow the use of an index on `sent` for the query.  By keeping all the time calculations on one side of the compare, we are, in essence, able to make the datetime calculation once for the entire query and then compare each row against that value using index on `sent`.

To see this difference in query speed, run that second query given above (with your current use of timestamps for `sent`) and compare against this query below, which would be analogous to you current approach:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`)
FROM `myTable`
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, FROM_UNIXTIME(`sent`), NOW()) > 5
```

You should see a significant difference at large table sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Max(id) and "sent" instead Max('id') and "'sent'"

Edit: ^--- This is partially wrong it is valid to use `id` and `sent`, but 'id' and 'sent' is not valid

Like this:

```
SELECT Max(id) FROM `mytable` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, sent, NOW()) > 5
```

EDIT: 
The problem is that you have stored "sent" as an integer, in order to use it with TIMESTAMPDIFF you'll have to convert it into the DATE_TIME format. 
Here is how you can do that:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(sent),NOW())
```

And the end result:

```js
SELECT Max(id) FROM `mytable` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(sent),NOW()) > 5
```

Some extra reading:
[Convert timestamp to date in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251561/convert-timestamp-to-date-in-mysql-query)

Comment: I did that and That one two gave me an empty result. Meanwhile  I have some stuff that i have inserted in the database for more than a month. So it should be able to get me at least those of more than 5 minutes

Comment: You are certain that you got anything in the table, right?
Worked for me with my tables :/
If you aren't using a mysql console it might be usefull to try there aswell.

Comment: I have just added my table structure. Please copy it to mysql and try it

Comment: Think I found the problem :)

Comment: No need to call `DATE_FORMAT()` here.  `FROM_UNIXTIME()` will return a valid datetime expression usable in `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`

Comment: @MikeBrant ok, didn't know that. Updated anwser