# convert time format in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a database table  in (**Drupal**) which time is stored in a format like **1328105887** . I want to write a *where* condition w.r.t. this date where is year is **2014** and output date will be in  **(d-m-y)** format.

**My table sturcture is like this**

```
SELECT `sid`,`nid`,`uid`,`is_draft`,`submitted`,`remote_addr` FROM `my_table`
```

Help me to achieve this only with mysql query .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp to date in MySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251561/convert-timestamp-to-date-in-mysql-query)

Comment: Which is this format ? Can you tell the equivalent date for **1328105887**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  from_unixtime(1328105887) from tableName
returns : 2012-02-01 19:18:07
```

Now

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(1328105887) ,'%m-%d-%Y') 
 returns: 02-01-2012
```

if you need just year use this:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(1328105887) ,'%Y') 
 returns: 2012
```

use it in where clause as:

```
where DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(1328105887) ,'%Y')='2014'
```

so the final query would be

```
  SELECT `sid`,`nid`,`uid`,`is_draft`,`submitted`,`remote_addr` FROM 
  `my_table` 
  where DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_column`),'%Y') = '2014'
```

Comment: yeah i tried but what about the where condition I need result of year  2014  only

Comment: @vipulsharma I have added that..check my answer .. i wrote the complete query in the end

Answer (score 0):

**Working**

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`submitted`), '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'date_formatted' FROM `ma_webform_submissions` where year(FROM_UNIXTIME(`submitted`)) = '2014'

Comment: it is okay,, since you marked my answer as answered. you don't need to write it again in answer :) ..