# How to use function with Table

Tags: mysql

I created a table in which i used timestamp column which tells the record is updated on that time and date.

```
create table age_info (age tinyint not null,created_on timestamp not null );
```

But i want to change display like this.
`select date_format(Now() ,'%W, %e %M %Y @ %r');`

```
Tuesday, 31 July 2015 @ 02:32:16 PM
```

But don't know how to do it. When i insert values

```
insert into age_info(age) values (19);
```

in the table it show like this.

```
age      created_on
 19     2015-07-31 18:55:01
```

I Don't know how to use this function `date_format` with timestamp column to show like that format.

Comment: Possibly this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251561/convert-timestamp-to-date-in-mysql-query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will help you to solve the answer

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`created_on` , '%W, %e %b %Y @ %r') FROM `age_info`;
```

To insert,

```
 INSERT INTO `age_info` (`age`) select DATE_FORMAT(now() , '%W %e, %b %Y @ %r')created_on from age_info
```

Note that, You need to change the table field to varchar.

Comment: @Kiran LM why you write WHERE 1 at query and what it's mean

Comment: no, that's just an example, to insert try this : `INSERT INTO `age_info` (`created_on`) select DATE_FORMAT(now() , '%W %e, %b %Y @ %r') as created_on from age_info`

Comment: @Kiran LM does date_format function used for only select statement

Comment: Yes, It used to display datetime format so mostly used in selects,

Comment: @Kiran LM  does there any way we can save record in that format

Comment: check out the edit in the answer, there is the insert query.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the format you want by changing your column definition to a text column. Is that what you really want? You'll lose all the benefits a timestamp column offers (easy date and time calculations, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the datetime column type to store the data as you want, it changes the meaning of the datetime and no advantage of it, although you can use it to select the format whatever you want using date_format() function.