# How to retrieve only the date from a Column that the Datatype is TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my database which the datetype is TimeStamp, but I want the only date part of this column not date and time, for example if the  time stamp is (2016-02-06 21:01:27) so I only want the (2016-02-06), So I need your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp to date in MySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251561/convert-timestamp-to-date-in-mysql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function

```
mysql> SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
        -> '2003-12-31'
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot @Nir Levy