# How to transform the timestamp in seconds, stored in database, to a "date" via ajax on the fly?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm a web dev beginner and got a problem with a timestamp and need your help!
I'm working on a posting formula and a posting displayer. In the formula, I save the posting timestamp in **"seconds"** into the database.
If the user clicks on a button, more information will show up, also the "creation date".
The user do have the choice via a **date configuration** how the **date** will get displayed, for example **month/day/year** or **day.month.year**, ...
That is the reason why I save the timestamp in seconds to the database and not directly in a date like: **month/day/year**

```
$tm = time();
```

So my ajax formula must fetch the timestamp in seconds from the database and transform it to a **date** on the fly.
I found in this forum a solution how to transform seconds to a date via javascript but I don't know how to implement it to **ajax**.

With my code I dont have problems to fetch information from database, it works perfectly fine, but I only know how to fetch the date in seconds, like: **1538395461**

Here is a shorter version of my code

## AJAX CODE

```
<script>
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("a.img_title");


for(var x=0; x < buttons.length; x++)
{
  buttons[x].addEventListener('click', loadDescr);
}

function loadDescr(e)
{
  var abc = e.target.getAttribute('data-xy');

  var xhr_ap = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr_ap.open('GET', 'includes/ajax/ajax_posts_conn.php?ref_desr=' + abc, true);

  xhr_ap.onload = function()
  {
    if (this.status == 200)
    {
      /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
      var post_header = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
      var output = '';

      for (var i in post_header)
      {
        output += '<ul>' +
          '<li><a>created: '+post_header[i].post_created+'</a></li>' +
          '</ul>';
      }
      document.getElementById('post_creation_date').innerHTML = output;
      /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    }
  }
  xhr_ap.send();
}
</script>
```

**"post_created"** is the name of the table row.
**"post_creation_date"** is the name of the div in my html, where the information get sent to.

Comment: Export it from MySQL in the correct format using `DATE_FORMAT` and `FROM_UNIXTIME`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp to date in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251561/convert-timestamp-to-date-in-mysql-query)

Comment: i said in the question, that the user do have a option, how the date gets displayed, if the date get saved as: "month/day/year", then i can't display it as "day.month.year" anymore or do you know whats to do then?

Comment: When using an RDBMS like MySQL it's usually better to save data in the native format, which for MySQL is a `DATETIME` column.

Comment: ok, if the date get saved as "datetime" like: 2018-10-13 00:00:01, how can i output the date in the post as like: 10/13/2018 or like 13.10.2018?

Comment: @Fourty-Two [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52597575/how-to-transform-the-timestamp-in-seconds-stored-in-database-to-a-date-via-a?noredirect=1#comment92129834_52597575)