# How to (group by) date for every day in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

For my site admin panel, i need to show statistics for payments between two date

My payments table fields:

```sql
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| price              | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| created            | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I need to get the payments data between tow days, day by day by php laravel to this structure

```php
// date between 2021-12-01 and 2021-12-03

$data = [
    [
        'date' => '2021-12-01',
        'count' => 5 // number of payments records in 2021-12-01 in payments table
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2021-12-02',
        'count' => 0 // number of payments records in 2021-12-01 in payments table
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2021-12-03',
        'count' => 15 // number of payments records in 2021-12-01 in payments table
    ],
];
```

You should know maybe a day i haven't any payment and in database this day hasen't any records. but i need to show this day with count of 0

I don't know how do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a recursive common table expression (in mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2+) to create your table of dates (here, reporting dates from 2021-01-01 to 2021-01-31):

```
with recursive dates as (
    select date('2021-01-01') date
    union all
    select dates.date + interval 1 day from dates where dates.date < '2021-01-31'
)
select dates.date, count(payments.id)
from dates
left join payments on date(payments.created)=dates.date
group by 1;
```

Comment: how to implement in laravel query builder?

Comment: @mohammad13 There's an extension https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-cte that provides support for recursive table expressions, but I don't know enough about laravel to show how to use it

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using this query:

```sql
select gen_date, count(transactions.id) from

(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) gen_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
 left JOIN  transactions
  on date(transactions.created) = date(gen_date)

where gen_date between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-20'
group by gen_date;
```

if you want laravel query builder version:

```
    $select = DB::query()->selectRaw("gen_date, count(transactions.id)")->fromSub(function ($query) {
        $query->select("(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) gen_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4)");
    }, "v")
        ->leftJoin('transactions', function ($join) {
            $join->on(DB::raw("date(transactions.created)"), "=", DB::raw("date(v.gen_date)"));
        })
        ->whereRaw("gen_date between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-20'")
        ->groupBy('gen_date')
        ->get();
```

ps: the date range subquery I taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251561/convert-timestamp-to-date-in-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DB::raw()`:

```php
$data = DB::raw('select left(created_at, 10) as date, count(1) as count from payments group by date;');
```

Comment: you should know. maybe a day i haven't any payment and in databse this day has any records. but i need to show this day with count of 0

Comment: Do that in a loop in your controller/frontend

Comment: i do but this is send many requests to database and this is actually incorrect way

Comment: No, you do one call to the database with the code I wrote, and then populate the empty days with in your controller/frontend.

Answer (score 0):

this code can show you the days of between two days

```sql
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-03'
```

i hobe this code can help you

Comment: This doesn't answer the question entirely.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT DATE(created) AS `date`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM source_table
-- WHERE created BETWEEN @period_start AND @period_finish
GROUP BY `date`;
```